# How to include 'Zendesk' mobile chat support in xamarin forms application

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to introduce 'Zendesk' chat support in my application. I have tried to search but not get the process of including. Please suggest any idea. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Zendesk documentation appears to only indicate native support for Android and iOS. Xamarin can link the SDKs individually for each build -- see Xamarin documentation for this (links included but not summarized due to length), but won't handle bridging the difference between the two. Windows will not be supported by this option. If you only want to target Android and iOS, you can use these options and create wrapper classes with a common interface.

Alternatively, if you badly need Windows support and are comfortable with web technologies, the web sdk offers a full api. Xamarin forms supports a webview in which you can load the web sdk, and either build a GUI in the webview or make api calls via the web sdk.

Links detailing including native libraries:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/using_native_libraries/
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/native_interop/

*Note -- above link is specifically for native libraries, which I believe is correct for Zendesk's SDK. If not, there is also a guide for objective-c libraries on the Xamarin website.*